# Do the hardiness and heat zone scores mean just for outdoor planting? What if I am planting inside?

Tags: hardiness-zone

I live in Chicago and am interested in topiary. I looked up possible plants and one of the ones I read was good for topiary was rosemary.

https://www.gardenia.net/plant/rosmarinus-officinalis-rosemary

When I looked up the requirements for growing it however, it says I am in approximately Hardiness 6 and Heat Zone 6, which doesn't match the requirements for rosemary.

However, I'm confused if these requirements are for indoor or outdoor planting. Obviously, in my apartment, it's 75 degrees year round. So would I consider inside my apartment to be a different hardiness zone and heat zone? Or is that considered 6a and 6 too?

Comment: Hardiness zone is for outdoors only, it is especially important for freezing, which is something many plants cannot deal with.

Comment: Herbs that originated in the Mediterranean region don't usually grow well indoors because the light level is too low. They need as much full sunlight as possible.

Comment: I've had very good luck with rosemary indoors - the plant has never left my house, and it's very healthy after 6 years. It's in an east window and gets anywhere from6 hrs (summer) to 3 hrs (winter) of sun. It must be in a very well drained potting mix.